What is this chip FN98?
I am repairing a Philips digital door lock. I found a broken chip. FN98 imprinted on it. It is 8 pin. It placed in supply zone.
Anyone does know this chip?




It's a MPS MP2322GQH step-down converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)

exactly , Thank you very much
